# $\kappa^{\lambda} \leq \boldsymbol{2}^{\lambda}$ where $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are infinite cardinals and $\kappa \leq \lambda$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am proving the following theorem:

If $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are both infinite cardinals and $\kappa \leq \lambda$, then $\kappa^{\lambda} = \boldsymbol{2}^{\lambda}$.

We are showing $\kappa^{\lambda} \leq \boldsymbol{2}^{\lambda}$ and $\boldsymbol{2}^{\lambda} \leq \kappa^{\lambda}$ to prove the theorem. The former is what I can't prove for now. It seems that I am not quite familiar with techniques involving infinite ordinals/cardinals.

Comment: Hint: can you show why $\lambda^\lambda \leq 2^{\lambda\times\lambda}$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Cross product? Is it cardinal product or the cross product?

Comment: The cardinal product (cross product makes no sense in that context).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I managed to finish the proof. Finally, we are using the infinity property to argue $\lambda \cdot \lambda = \lambda$, and get what we want. Just curious how to get such intricate thoughts.